# Dojo Forms. How to show errors about incorrect filled form elements like dijit method validate() does?

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo

I am using dojo forms and submitting using AJAX. I use 2 methods of validate: [on client side](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/Form.html#dijit-form-form) and on server side:

```
dojo.connect(form, "onsubmit", function(event){
    dojo.stopEvent(event);

    var digit_form = dijit.byId("user_profile_form");
    if (!digit_form.validate()) {
        return false;
    }
//  client-side validation is ok, so we submit form using AJAX

    var xhrArgs = {
        form: form,
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function(responseText){
            // here I get response from server
            // and if there are errors on server
            // responseText object contains array with errors, so I
            // need to show this errors to user 
        },
        error: function(error) {
        }
    }

    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
}
```

The problem is that [validate()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/Form.html#dijit-form-form) method shows nice error messages to user, but when I get errors from server I can't show errors like method validate() does, so I use native javascript alert() method that is not so nice. I would like equal displaying of errors that validates on server and client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each server side error, set a new `widget.SSError` property.

```
error: function(error) {
    widget.set('SSError','The value is invalid because server thought so...'
    form.validate();
}
```

Override the `widget.isValid()` function and make it check the new `widget.SSError` property.

[Based on this message](http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2010-March/044222.html),

```
var myCustomFS = dojo.declare(dijit.form.FIlteringSelect, {
    postMixInProperties: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);

        // Point _isValidOld at the function isValid currently points at
        this._isValidOld = this.isValid;

        // Point isValid at a new function
        this.isValid = function() {
            if (this.SSError) {
                return false;
            }
            return this._isValidOld(); // Calls the original isValid function
        }
    }
};
```

Put a watch on the value and reset `widget.SSError` when it changes.

```
widget.watch('value', function(){
    widget.set('SSError', false)
})
```

Comment: Nice, seems like a neat approach.

Comment: nice solution thx, but i think it must be "return this._isValidOld()"